# Comments in the .net class library

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2013, documentation

I am creating .NET class library, for each class I am adding a documentation on the top of the class:

```
/// <summary>
///     Contains helper functions for ...
/// </summary>
public static class MyHelperClass
{
      /// <summary>
      ///     Helper function for ...
      /// </summary>
      public static void HelperFunction() {}
}
```

Now, when I compiled the library and added it as a reference to my other project, when I am trying to use this class I don't see the documentation e.g. on the top of the class:

```
MyHelperClass.HelperFunction(); -> Intellisense won't show up my comments
```

I am wondering if I need to set some flag when I am building the library?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to check the `Generate XML documentation file` checkbox in the Build tab in Project Properties.